# How to access subitems of a div that's copied to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my webpage I have a DIV of the class "editor" that I copy into a variable.

```
editorTemplate = $('.editor');
```

The DIV looks like this (simplified):

```
<div class="editor">
  <div>
    Title: <span class="title" id="title">  the title goes here  </span><br />
    <select class="recording_list" id="recording_list">
      <option value="1">Pos 1</option>
      <option value="2">Pos 2</option>
      ...
    </select>
</div>  <!-- class=editor -->
```

Later I want to create a series from that div by adding it to the page:

```
$(editArea).append(editorTemplate);
```

So far so good.

But I want to change some attributes - like the IDs of the fields, some text and the selected element of the option box - before pasting the editor template onto the page.

I can change the ID of the edit template with

```
$(myEdit).attr("id", "edit" + nEditors);
```

But I don't know how to access the INNER elements of the template, e.g. the ID and the text of the "title" field.

After the template is pasted into the page I can say

```
$('#title').attr("id", "title" + nEditors);
$('#title').html("the new text");
...
```

Is it possible to make these changes BEFORE I paste the template into the page?

Comment: `On my webpage I have a DIV of the class "editor" that I copy into a variable.` You are not copying the elements. You are merely creating a jQuery wrapper variable named `editorTemplate` which is a pointer to the DOM elements matching the selector. This is important to know as later when you do `append(editorTemplate)` you will end up `moving` the DOM elements rather than copying a new version. If you want to make a copy of the DOM elements, manipulate them and append them later, use [**clone()**](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) on the elements you wish to make a copy of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the [JQuery.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method.

```
var editorTemplate = $('.editor');
editorTemplate.children('<selectors to uniquely identify the child object>').<method to update the content accordingly>
```

So then we could do something like this...

```
count=1;
editorTemplate.children('span#title').html('<Update HTML here>').attr('id','title_'+count);
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I just noticed that your elements are at multiple levels so using [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) would be ideal as it can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

Answer (score 4):

You are not copying the elements into a variable.

```
editorTemplate = $('.editor');
```

The above creates a jQuery wrapper with a set of pointers which point to the DOM elements. The wrapper allows you to execute jQuery methods targeting the DOM elements.

If you do `editorTemplate.find("#title").attr("id", "newId")` on that it changes the `id` attribute of the element you are currently pointing at in the DOM not a new copy.

When you are planning on doing this later:

```
$(editArea).append(editorTemplate);
```

The above will not append a new copy of the DOM elements but instead will be `moving` the elements you point at through the `editorTemplate` wrapper from their original location in the DOM to the new location in the DOM `editArea` is referencing.

If you planning on making duplicates of some elements within `editorTemplate` to append them later you would use jQuery `clone()`, similar to this:

```
// use clone(true, true) to also clone any attached events
var editorTemplate = $('.editor').clone();

// Using .find you can change attribute in your new copy/clone
editorTemplate.find("#title").attr("id", "title" + nEditors).html("the new text");

// append your new copy/clone
$(editArea).append(editorTemplate);
```

Comment: @user2035236 - Generally good questions attract more eyeballs.. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint.I'm a complete JS newbie and will do a lot of that kind of mistakes, I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

You cam use find method to get access to your elements:

```
var editorTemplate = $('.editor');

$(editorTemplate).find('#title').attr('id', 'title' + nEditors).html('the new text');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
editorTemplate.clone()
              .attr({})
              .find("select").attr({id:"whatever"}).end()
              .find("span").....end()
              .appendTo($(editarea))
```

i hope you get the idea